# Drawing a Fractal Tree by Processing

Tags: java, image-processing, recursion, processing, fractals

I want to draw a fractal tree in processing, but I don't know how to make it. And my idea is to draw a binary tree. But the tree must have more branches. And I don't know how to code it. Please help me, thanks.Now i have drawn a 2D Tree, but my boss ask me to change it to 3D.And this is my code,and i don't know how to make it.And i'm a fresh man in Processing programing.Please help me.

```
void tree(float treeLength, float strokeWeight, int currentTreeStep)
{
    if (currentTreeStep < maxTreeSteps) {

        if(currentTreeStep >= 8 && currentTreeStep <=10)
            stroke(#558351); //set color light green
        else{
            if(currentTreeStep >10 && currentTreeStep <=20)
                stroke(#199B0E); //set hard green        
            else{
                stroke(#311919);//set branch color
            }
        }
        strokeCap(PROJECT);
        strokeWeight(strokeWeight);
        line(0, 0, 0, -treeLength);  
        translate(0, -treeLength);

        strokeWeight *= 0.5;
        treeLength *= 0.75;

        if (treeLength > 1) {
            pushMatrix();
            rotate(radians(branchAngle));
            tree(treeLength, strokeWeight, currentTreeStep + 1);
            popMatrix();

            pushMatrix();
            rotate(-radians(branchAngle));
            tree(treeLength, strokeWeight, currentTreeStep + 1);
            popMatrix();
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Which part of that is giving you trouble? Where is your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Note that the Processing editor comes with a ton of examples, including several on fractal trees.

Comment: Thanks for your help,and i had fixed the 2D tree through Google.But there is a problem how to change it to 3D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally it's not as intuitive as one might to move from 2D(trigonometry mostly) to 3D(linear algebra: vector and matrix multiplication).

Have a look at this [example](http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/7251) from one of the courses I did.

[image]

Hopefully you'll also see the 3D matrix multiplication part in action as well

Comment: I run your code in my processing,but it can not run,I fixed some problems,and it can not run.I have to change Vector to PVector,but the complier say "the method get(float[]) in the type Pvector is not applicable for the arguments (float)"(I run it in Processing 3.0a5).And there is my code i changed.                                                                  for (int i = 0; i < children.mag(); i++) {
      pushMatrix();
      Node n = (Node) children.get(i);
      n.draw();
      popMatrix();
    }

Comment: @WangYao Vector refers to [java.util.Vector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) which a resizable/dynamic array roughly. Please don't replace that with PVector. Simply add this line: ```import java.util.Vector;```. Processing 2.0 and newer removed the import to ```java.util.*``` which is why you're getting the error

Comment: Thank you so much,I fixed it by your guide.And thank you again.I'm sorry my reputation doesn't reach the 15.I can not vote up for your answer.So sorry.

Comment: @samgak,thank you,I have accepted.Thanks for your help.

Comment: i meet a problem in proceeing, can you answer this, thanks. This my  [Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054809/convert-string-to-float-occurs-nan-error-in-processing)