# Convert string to float occurs NaN error in Processing

Tags: java, arduino, processing

I meet a problem in the Processing, and when i convert the value(string) into float, the first value is good, but the rests are all `NaN`. I could not find a way to solve this. And i print the string value for test. And it is correct, but after i convert it into float. It will be `NaN`.

ps: the value is from the serial, i connected my Arduino with Proceesing.

**following is a part of codes**

```java
while(myport.available() > 0)
  {
    myString = myport.readString(); //read the string from serial
    num = float(myString);          // convert the string into float
    print(num);                     // print the num(float), but the first 
                                    // value is good, rests are all `NaN` .
    //print(myString);              // print string, all the values are good
    print(' ');
    if(myString != null)
    {
       //num = float(myString);
       storeData(myString);
       //println(myString);
       //print(data[i - 1]);
       //println(' ');
       delay(1000);
    }
   }
```

**following is the result**

### conversion finshed:

[image]

### not convert, only print string value

[image]

**following is arduino code**

```c
  sum = sqrt(Xg*Xg + Yg*Yg + Zg * Zg);
  sum *= 10;  
  sum = (map(sum, 0, 1024, 0, 5000)/10.0);
  Serial.println(sum);
  delay(100);
```

Comment: I think you need to convert each character in the string to a float? Try iterating over the characters in the string, and calling foat(c) on each of them.

Comment: Are you sure that's what you get when you print out the `myString` variable? That doesn't make a ton of sense: where are all those newlines coming from? You're using the `print()` function instead of the `println()` function, so they should all be one one line.

Comment: @flutillie do you have an example code for this conversion? If you do, please post it, thanks.

Comment: @KevinWorkman in arduino serial port monitor, `myString` values are same with Processing. And either the newline.

Comment: Can you post your arduino code? The problem is there, probably.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I will, thanks.

Comment: @Peto I add arduino code

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is not inside Arduino but inside the Processing code.

I was looking a lot and I note that there is an error that can most likely solve your problem.

You used `val = myport.readString();` *instead of* `val = myport.readStringUntil('\n');` .

The differences are few, but in your case would be substantial.
Take a look at [ReadString](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/Serial_readString_.html) function and [ReadStringUntil](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/Serial_readStringUntil_.html) function.

Anyway, it is also suggested by the [sparkFun tutorial](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/connecting-arduino-to-processing).

P.S. Of course, in your Arduino code, you *have to use* (well, like you were doing) `Serial.println(sum);` instead of `Serial.print(sum)` because, in the last case, that would not send to processing nothing before a line feed has been sended.

Comment: I fixed my problem [Sending float variables over serial](http://www.varesano.net/blog/fabio/sending-float-variables-over-serial-without-loss-precision-arduino-and-processing), and thanks for your help.@Peto

Comment: I cannot see your link (my anti-virus blocked it) but if you want you could answer yourself (without link, that could also change in time) helping other users. You're welcome ;)

Comment: I will. Thanks. @Peto

Answer (score 0):

I find my problem is inside the Arduino code, so i changed the way to send the data from Arduino. I used the `println()` to send the data. And that's the point lead to `NaN`. I serached on google, and then i tested different ways to change the way to send until i finded this link:http://www.varesano.net/blog/fabio/sending-float-variables-over-serial-without-loss-precision-arduino-and-processing

And thanks fabio's blog, his blog's introudces a good way to solve this problem. If you have the same trouble, maybe you can fixed by this.